# Cursor .foreach and array data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I use the cursor `.forEach` to display the data as a table.

```
.forEach(function(doc){
        print((doc.Id + ';' + doc.item + ';' + doc.delta);
```

But this does not work with data like this:

```
items" : [
    {
        "amount" : 1,
        "id" : 158,
}]
```

How do I bring them to the table using the cursor?

I need something like this:

```
id-itemId-amount 

57 | 158 | 1

58 | 159 | 2
```

(itemID and amount from array)

Answer (score 1):

The Mongo shell supports standard JavaScript for iterating over an array and the `items` attribute *is* an array. So, inside the 'for each function' you can iterate over the `items` array and print out the `id` and `amount` attributes for each subdocment in that array.

For example:

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    // standard JS loop over an array
    for (var i in doc.items) {
        // print the id from the 'outer' document alongside the id  
        // and amount from each sub document in the items array
        print(doc.id + '|' + doc.items[i].id + '|' + doc.items[i].amount);
    }
})
```

Given the following documents ...

```
{ "id": 1, items" : [{"amount": 10, "id": 158}, {"amount": 11, "id": 159}]}
{ "id": 2, items" : [{"amount": 20, "id": 266}, {"amount": 21, "id": 267}]}
```

... the above function will print:

```
1|10|158
1|11|159
2|20|266
2|21|267
```